# How can I use LaTeX to draw a 2D grid with self-loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

Is it possible to draw a 2D grid with self-loop like in image below in LaTeX?
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Ok! Sorry for not knowing the rules. So what's the difference between TeX.SX and TeX site? I‘m still confused about it.

Comment: TeX.SX is the usual abbreviation for TeX.StackExchange.com

Comment: Oh I see, but why it has two TeX sites? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The TeX.Meta site is for question about the TeX site.

Comment: LOL, I got it. Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though I fully agree with @egreg, I'd like to give you a "welcome present".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm] (-3.8,-3.8) grid (3.8,3.8);
\foreach \i in {-3,...,3}
{
\foreach \j in {-3,...,3}
{
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=\i cm,yshift=\j cm}]
\draw[rotate=45,-latex] (0,0) arc [start angle=180,end angle=-120,x radius=0.3,y radius=0.1]
node[right,xshift=0.2cm,yshift=0.4cm] {$\ell$};
\draw node[draw,circle,fill=white] at (0,0) {};
\end{scope}
}
}
\draw (0,0) circle (0.125cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you add `\usetikzlibrary{bending}`, the arrows will look much nicer. (+1) by the way.

Comment: @AboAmmar You're right, but I'm gonna spare this for future answers (and I had problems getting the bends when the coordinates became to close to each other...) ;-)